# Threaded Binary Trees

Tags: data-structures

Since trees are special kind of graphs or we can categorize trees in DAG(Directed Acyclic Graphs) but how can we differentiate between Threaded Binary Trees and Graphs? Can we categorize threaded binary tree in DAG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A threaded binary tree is not a DAG, since it has cycles, *but* it is easy to treat it as one in any algorithm by not following threads (think treating them as NULL pointers).

It is also easy to convert any Threaded Binary Tree into a Binary Tree by removing all the threads.